# Respawn AI after destroy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new, and I've got hard time to respawn my AI (right now he just a cube that follow my player) after he been destroy. I believe its because the script sits on the object that get destroyed. but what I need to do to respawn it?

(although I'm sure my respawn code is not good :\ (It's mobile-android project) )

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyTesting : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject enemy;
    private Rigidbody body;

    Vector3 accelerationDir;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        accelerationDir = Input.acceleration;

        if (accelerationDir.sqrMagnitude>=5)
        {
            EnemyDead();
        }
    }

    void EnemyDead()
    {

        Destroy(enemy);
        Invoke("Respawn", 5);
    }
    void Respawn()
    {
        enemy = (GameObject)Instantiate(enemy);
        enemy.transform.position = transform.position;
    }
   

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 toTarget = player.transform.position - transform.position;
        float speed = 1.5f;

        transform.Translate(toTarget * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: You are destroying the `enemy` instance .. so how do you want to use it as prefab for `Instantiate` 5 seconds later? What about rather only set it to inactive/active instead and don't destroy and Respawn it at all?

Comment: But I want to Respawn it, if ill inactive it and reactive, it will just activated it from where he inactivated.

Comment: Well set it inactive -> move to the new position -> reset other values if needed (like health etc) -> set active .... => Acts like a respawn without actually causing the overhead of destroy and Instantiate

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing that your `enemy` GameObject is inside the scene holding your `EnemyTesting` MonoBehaviour instance (correct me if I'm wrong).

If this is the case, you cannot instantiate a gameObject that is destroyed.

As @derHugo pointed out, [you should not use Destroy and Instantiate for your use case](https://www.noveltech.dev/why-avoid-runtime-instantiation-unity/). It would be better to set inactive the `enemy` GameObject, move it to the position that you want, an (re)set it active. It will look like the enemy respawned.

*If you want to dig the subject later, look at the [object pooling game optimization pattern](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html).*

---

Otherwise, if you still want to use Instantiate for respawning, I would [create a prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingPrefabs.html) of your `enemy` GameObject. The `enemy` GameObject referenced in the `EnemyTesting` field (in the Inspector view), would be your prefab from the project hierarchy instead of a GameObject inside the scene.

This way, you would be able to instantiate an `enemy` GameObject as many times as you want (and use it in other scenes!). Don't forget to hold a reference to the instantiated `enemy` GameObject so you can know which one you want to destroy. It would looke like this :

```
enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
```

You can replace `transform` with the transform of your choice, for example the transform of an empty `enemyRespawnPoint` GameObject in your Scene.

*Do you see any error in the console ?*